# Using a Sort algorithm to sort a list of strings

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, list, sorting

I'm was wondering if anyone can show me how to sort a list of strings using a sorting algorithm in alphabetical order?

I know I can simply use `List<string>.Sort()` however it would be great to understand how to write it as a string sorting algorithm.

Currently I've understood how to implement a sorting algorithm when it comes with integer values but I'm struggling when it comes to dealing with strings in a list.

```
    // sort a vector of type int using exchange sort
    public void ExchangeSort(int[] array)
    {
        int pass, i, n = array.Length;
        int temp;
        // make n-1 passes through the data 
        for (pass = 0; pass < n - 1; pass++)
        {
            // locate least of array[pass] ... array[n - 1]  
            // at array[pass] 
            for (i = pass + 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] < array[pass])
                {
                    temp = array[pass];
                    array[pass] = array[i];
                    array[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not an exact answer but you may check this out http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: For sorting there is a compare operation and a swap operation (move).  So, for alphabetic strings the compare operation would change.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this exactly like your int sorter, but instead of

```
if (array[i] < array[pass])
```

you would use

```
var comp = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
....
if (comp.Compare(array[i],array[pass]) < 0)
```

There are several [standard string comparers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx) provided by Microsoft, such as ones that use the current culture, the invariant culture, that ignore case and so on.

If you want to write your own compare function, the simplest method is to go through both strings in a for loop, and compare each character to each other. I would however not recommend doing that unless it is strictly for learning purposes, since getting your own comparison to work correctly for all corner cases of unicode and different languages is very hard.

Answer (score 0):

the comparison of strings can be done with the string.Compare function. to do this manually, it can get quite complicated, because there are many different options.

one possibilty would be comparing just the ascii values, like this

```
bool isLarger(string s1, string s2)
{ 
return Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(s1.Length, s2.Length)).SkipWhile(i => s1[i] == s2[i]).Select(i => s1[i] > s2[i]).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

for a good comparison, there exists many options like descriped in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareinfo(v=vs.80).aspx